# qt installer framework visual redistributable

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I'm trying to make an installer for my Qt app with the help of qt installer framework. I've created the installer, but it refuses to run because of the missing **vcruntime140.dll** and **msvcp140.dll**. I figured out that they are included in visual c++ redistributable packet. I've added the **VC_redist.x64.exe** into my installer and installscript. But this didn't help. The error seems to appear before the sript execution. Any ideas if there is a way to edit the installscript so that everything works as expected?

**installscript**

```
function Component()
{
    // constructor
    component.addElevatedOperation("Execute", "{0,1602,1638}", "@TargetDir@\\VC_redist.x64.exe", "/passive", "/norestart");
    
}
```

---

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
   ...
    <Default>true</Default>
    <Script>installscript.qs</Script>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like installer was broken in version 4.x
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-2137

The only workaround is to install vc redistributable (x86) manually or use older version of ifw